# Tables in Google Analytics: calculating % of total in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am analyzing two segments (based on an existing dimension) in a table in a Google Analytics dashboard and I want to know how to add a column and insert a calculation that calculates the % of Total each segment comprises of the total visits?

Furthermore, is it possible to have a table with more than 3 columns? I can't seem to find a way to add more columns without adding additional widgets.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do calculations based on Google Analytics data, I export the data to a spread sheet and do the calculations in a spread sheet.  I haven't found a way to have Google Analytics do those calculations in a new column for me.